# I cannot access POST, getting GET instead

Tags: html, node.js, reactjs, express, axios

recently I decided to learn something new and I have come across NodeJS and ReactJS and I am glad to be learning them. But there is something I need help with. On the server side, I installed a few packages like MySQL, body-parser, nodemon, express, and cors. I wanted the front-end to communicate with the back-end server. It worked perfectly just before I reinstalled a Windows 10. Now when I create a POST function on server-side and try to execute it using Axios in my front-end, I get this value:

```
Cannot GET /api/register/
```

I didn't use any form tag in my project before I reinstalled Windows and it worked perfectly.. so why is there GET instead of POST? I even followed this tutorial

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3YrOOia3-mo (all three parts of the series)

BACK-END CODE:

```
const express = require('express')
const app = express()
const mysql = require('mysql')
const bodyParser = require('body-parser')
const cors = require('cors')


app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(cors());    //Allow not to encounter errors


const db = mysql.createPool({
    host: 'localhost',
    user: 'root',
    password: 'password',
    database: 'mydtb'
})

app.post('/api/register/', (req, res) => {
    const userN = req.body.user;
    const passW = req.body.pass;
    const sql = "INSERT INTO users (username, password) VALUES (?,?)";

    db.query(sql, [userN, passW], (err, result) =>{
        res.send(result);
        console.log(res);
    });
});

app.post('/api/values/', (req, res) => {

    const sql = "INSERT INTO users (username, password) VALUES ('lucashello','ma45sd4ye')";
    db.query(sql, (err, result) =>{
        res.send(result);
    });
});


app.get('/api/get', (req, res) => {

    const sql = "SELECT * FROM users";
    db.query(sql, (err, result) => {
        res.send(result);
    });
});

app.listen(3001, () => {console.log('Server is listening on port 3001')})
```

FRONT-END (only importat part of the code):

```
Axios.post('http://localhost:3001/api/register/', {user: username, pass: password}).then(()=>{
          
          setErrorArray(['Successfully registered!'])
          setErrorText(errorArray.map((arr) => {
            return <div key={arr} style={{color: 'green'}}>{arr}</div>
          }))
    })

return (
    <div className="App">
        <div className="login-form">
            <h1>Register</h1>
            <label htmlFor="username">Username:</label><br/>
            <input type="text" name="username" onChange={(e) => {setUsername(e.target.value)}}/><br/>
            <label htmlFor="password">Password:</label><br/>
            <input  type="password" name="password" onChange={(e) => {setPassword(e.target.value)}}/><br/>
            <label htmlFor="repeat-password">Repeat password:</label><br/>
            <input type="password" name="repeat-password" onChange={(e) => {setPasswordRepeat(e.target.value)}}/><br/>
            <span><button onClick={submitForm} className="button">Register</button> You can log in here</span><br/>
            {errorText}
        </div>
    </div>
  );
```

My database works perfectly, I tested it.. even the functions inside the form are correct, I think.. Am I missing something? Help me out, please, so I can know how to fix this if it happens again.

Comment: Could you please add the entire frontend code where you are making the request?

Comment: Yes, it's pasted here: https://pastebin.com/8QnVaVZ1

Comment: There are some mistakes in the frontend code but my question is are you making any `GET` request anywhere because that shouldn't happen. I ran your code after fixing the errors and it works fine.

Comment: Add `value` fields in all the inputs and set it equal to the corresponding `states`. Secondly, change `const [errorArray, setErrorArray] = useState([""]);` to `const [errorArray, setErrorArray] = useState([]);` as `errorArray.length` will always be `1` in the previous case.

Comment: @zx01 Thanks for your answer! The thing is, I am getting GET responds from /api/get.. That just gives me the JSON of my database table.. And it works just fine! So I don't know where the problem is.

Comment: I am confused now. What is the issue you are facing now? I mean if you are making `POST` request, then your code should enter `api.post` block, not `api.get` block.

Comment: We didn't understand each other or maybe I said something wrong... I can't access api/register from my front-end.. and even if I write it manually inside the browser, it writes Cannot GET api/register.. even if it's POST request.. It just completely ignores the part of the code where I define api.post('api/register'.....). Do we understand each other now? api.get works just fine.. only api.post doesn't.

Comment: Yes. Now, if you are running the frontend code which you have provided, then its impossible that it would enter the `api.get` block. Because I copied the same code, made some changes (mentioned above) and it works fine. Just check once whether you are running the same frontend code. It is possible that you might be running some other file.

Comment: I know it wouldn't.. It would enter the api.post.. but I was telling you that GET works even if I try that from the code or web browser.. but POST doesn't.... from the code and even from the browser.. I fixed the problems you have told me.. does it work for you?

Comment: Thats strange! Yup, it is working for me. Could you please provide a screenshot of the error?

Comment: How can I get error out of that function? .catch? Or what?

Comment: No no I meant the screenshot of this message `Cannot GET /api/register/`. I wanted to see the stack trace or anything as such.

Comment: GET http://localhost:3001/api/register 404 (Not Found) ..... Don't know why it's still GET..

Comment: Could you please try removing `bodyParser` package as it is deprecated. Use this instead `app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true }));`.

Comment: Done, but nothing changed.. Isn't this caused by a fact that I have a folder loginsystem/ and inside of the folder there are subfolders server and client... it's like separated from each other..

Comment: Nope that shouldn't be a problem. Try this code which works for me. Copy both the client and server side codes. Let me know if it works for you. [Server](https://www.codepile.net/pile/DAzvL7AM) [Client](https://www.codepile.net/pile/2EXZwGAj).

Comment: Okay, now it works somehow.. I don't know where the errors was.. don't you know by an accident? I spammed the register button and it only counts to 6 outputs.... is it ok?

Answer (score 0):

you have problem with routing in express. I solved the problem and upload to github

https://github.com/MykhailoDev/express-server

Comment: It still doesn't work.. It says the same after I uploaded all the files and imported all the things I've been missing.

Answer (score 0):

Your code looks good to me, if you can make backend calls with no problem via POSTMAN or INSOMNIA

it's worth trying to add a proxy in the frontend package.json:

```
"proxy": "http://127.0.0.1:<backend port>"
```

import axios without the capital "A" after react in your App.js:

```
import React, {useState} from 'react';    
import axios from 'axios';
```

And make the post to your backend as the following:

```
axios.post("/api/register", ...)
```

Comment: It works now with it or without it.. so I don't know..